# Help solving $ \int dx = \int \frac{1}{t} (1+2\ln(t))\,\tan(t)\,dt$ with bounds $ x \ge 0, t>0 $

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Normally I could figure out how to solve integrals and I require some help in the more conceptual or forumla type stuff. However this integral has been kicking my ass

$$ \int dx =\int \frac{(1+2\ln(t))\,\tan(t)}{t}\,dt$$ with bounds $ x >=0, t>0 $

So I attempted to do this using integration by parts, and at first I let $u=\tan(t) $ and $dv= \frac{1+2\ln(t)}{t}$ however as I kept doing it and doing it, it just got uglier and uglier and more confusing and just ended up in a huge mess.

I even tried using one of those online calculators and it didn't work.

[This is the full question](https://i.gyazo.com/1b9673e5947e5b0ca921827f97d5319d.png)

Comment: Mathematica couldn't work out the answer, so it is likely that this does not have elementary / Mathematica representable integral.

Comment: Are you certain you have to compute the *indefinite* integral here? No bounds given? And it's not a differentiating under the integral sign sort of question? Better to reproduce the exact question if you're not certain. There are too many instances of people posting partial questions that are intractable or much more difficult than they need be, when the actual original problem is solvable much more simply.

Comment: Ah, my mistake, the actual question was [like so](https://i.gyazo.com/1b9673e5947e5b0ca921827f97d5319d.png). I asked a friend on how I would do this and he simply gave me that integral and told me how he got it and told me to solve it. Kinda forgot there were these bounds (x >= 0, t > 0)

Comment: @WildWombat $x$ is a function of $t$? And the $\geq 0$ part can't simplify the problem.

Comment: This is a differential equation where integral(dx) = integral(what's up there), and those were the bounds given to us. I posted the link to the question in my comment up there.